# Transparent GPUImageView?

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I am using a GPUImageView inside my iOS application. I want that the GPUImageView have a transparent background.
I tried setBackground:[UIColor clearColor]
It does not work.
Any workarounds?

Regards

Answer (score 11):

I found you need to set both of these to get a transparent background. Neither works alone.

```
strengthPreviewImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[strengthPreviewImageView setBackgroundColorRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0];
```

Answer (score 3):

...Did you try the method from the GPUImageView header?

```
- (void)setBackgroundColorRed:(GLfloat)redComponent green:(GLfloat)greenComponent blue:(GLfloat)blueComponent alpha:(GLfloat)alphaComponent;
```

Comment: setBackgroundColorRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.0
gives a white background