# GPUImage - ChromaKeyBlendFilter - sourceImage

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, gpuimage, gpuimagestillcamera

I have an `GPUImageStillCamera` layered over a `UIView` (on which some realtime animation is happening) in which for `GPUImagePicture` I am passing the `sourceImage` with `smoothlyScaleOutput:YES` for `ChromaKeyBlendFilter`

The code works perfectly (most humble thanks to Brad Larson!) and I get a camera feed with green pixels removed where the `sourceImage` is shown.

What I want to do is to pass a `sourceImage` which could name the background transparent for the feed i.e. I don't want to show the `sourceImage` in background where the green pixels are removed but instead, I want that pixel to be transparent.

Here's the image from my project:[image]
See that blurry square area in the center, I want it to be transparent so that it shows the actual background image which is absolutely clear. right now I am passing the background image separately to the filter and it is showing blurry image.

To achieve the same, I tried with passing the transparent PNG but, I got a black color background. 
What should I be doing to achieve the thing I am looking for?
Please suggest.. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please make a mockup image of what you're trying to do. I read that paragraph several times but I still can't quite make out what you're trying to do. Maybe you can make a screenshot of Debug View Hierarchy, with what you have now and what views you want to switch?

Comment: please check the question again. i have added the screenshot

Comment: I am really sorry, but I can't understand what you want to achieve too. May you please rephrase question and/or add image of final result you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to make the background of `GPUImageView` transparent. As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15259959), you can do it by setting both of the following properties:

```
strengthPreviewImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[strengthPreviewImageView setBackgroundColorRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0];
```

Comment: i don't think it this would work. please check the question again. i have added the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You can try by setting up the filter's "thresholdSensitivity" by using UISlider.

```
[(GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter *)filter setThresholdSensitivity:[(UISlider *)sender value]];
```